# What is the difference between &p and p

Tags: c, address-operator

if I have a pointer to an integer such as:

```
int num = 12;
int *p = &num;
```

and then print the address so

```
printf("%p\n", (void*)p);
```

What is the difference between the previous and this:

```
printf("%p\n", (void*)&p);
```

Comment: The pointer is a variable too. You're taking the pointer's address in the second case.

Comment: `(void*)&p` means the **address** of p. Whereas `(void*)p` means the contents of p.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here, `p` contains the address of `num`, so the first `printf` outputs the address of `num`.

On the other hand, `&p` is the address of `p`, so the second `printf` prints the address of `p`.

Answer (score 2):

With the `"%p"` format, using only plain `p` will print the contents of the variable `p`, i.e. the address that the pointer variable `p` is pointing to.

When you use `&p` you get the address of the variable `p`, i.e. a pointer to `p` (in your case of type `int **`) and print that pointer.

You can look at it this way:

```
+----+    +---+    +-----+
| &p | -> | p | -> | num |
+----+    +---+    +-----+
```

In other words, `&p` points to `p` which points to `num`.

---

If you continue and try using `*p` then that won't work as you expect. It will dereference the pointer `p`, i.e. it will result in the value at the location were `p` is pointer (the variable `num` and its value, in this specific case). `*p` is a value of type `int` and trying to use the format `"%p"` to print it will lead to *undefined behavior*, because `*p` is not a pointer but a value and the `"%p"` format expects a pointer.

Most likely nothing bad will happen, and on a system where the size of a pointer is the same as the size of an `int` (which is most 32-bit systems out there) then the statement

```
printf("%p", (void *) *p);
```

would just print `c`, which is the hexadecimal value `12`, which is the value of `num`.

However if the size of a pointer is *not* the same as the size of a `int`,  like on a typical 64-bit system, then the output will not be something predictable, and will mostly seem totally random.

Answer (score 2):

Taking your example -

```
int num = 12;
int *p = &num;                     // store address of num in pointer p
printf("%p\n", (void*)p);          // line 1
printf("%p\n", (void*)&p);         // line 2
```

*line 1*- In this it will print address of variable `num` stored in pointer `p`. So, value stored in pointer `p` is address of integer variable `num`.

*line 2* - In this address of pointer `p` itself will be printed.  Note the use of *address of* operator . It gives address of pointer `p`.

Answer (score 1):

`(void*)&p` means the **address** of p.

`(void*)p` means the **contents** of p (in this case the **address** of `num`).

`(void*)*p` means the **contents** of what the variable `p` points to (`12`) (**value** of `num`).

See http://www.c4learn.com/c-programming/c-pointer-address-operator/ for more details about the **address operator**.

Comment: Not correct. `*p` is the contents of p. `(void *)p` is a cast.

Comment: @stackoverflowuser2010 I did not explain myself correctly. I said "contents" of p. I meant the address of num. Sorry. Thanks for bringing that to my attention. Is my answer more accurate now? Please confirm.

Comment: The second point is now awkwardly phrased. `p` by itself is just the contents of `p` regardless of the context of this question. In this particular case of OP's question, `p` is the address of `num`, so its contents is indeed the address of `num`.

Comment: @stackoverflowuser2010 I am happy for you to tweak my grammar if you feel the need. Thanks all the same for your comments. Appreciated.

Comment: @stackoverflowuser2010 I have revised it now.

Comment: Now it is clear. I am not commenting about your grammar but rather the meaningful content of your answer.

Answer (score 1):

The former prints the address of num. 
And the latter prints the address of the pointer p. 
Because, everything needs a location in memory to be stored.

If you take an integer, 
It has a physical address where its been stored, and data(an integer) stored in that location.

If you take a pointer, 
It also has a physical address where it is stored in memory, but here the data becomes another address which is the address of some integer variable.

& is called address of operator. It returns the memory address where a particular variable is stored. 
Following the same example,

> printf("%p\n", (void*)p);

Prints the data where the pointer p is pointing to. I.e., address of num.

Similar result can be obtained using,

> printf("%p\n", (void*)&num);

Hence, both will produce the same result.

Whereas,

> printf("%p\n", (void*)&p);

Prints the address of pointer p.

Answer (score 1):

```
printf("%p\n", (void*)p);
```

prints the value that `p` contains, which is the address of `num`.

```
printf("%p\n", (void*)&p);
```

prints the address of the pointer `p` itself.

Answer (score 0):

There are two types arguments which you can pass in a c/c++ functions.

1st one is call by value which calls in a program something like (void)p,  which is copying the same value and the value in that particular void function will not change.

2nd one is call by reference which actually goes into memory and find out that particular location/address and changes its value there. which is in your case (void)&p